# NDVI Imagery for Iran

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uses-of-open-data, images, land-cover

I'm trying to find a good source of [NDVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_difference_vegetation_index) imagery (vegetation), but I'm struggling to find proper high resolution imagery for Iran.

Does anyone have references to NDVI imagery (at sub-10m resolution) for 2012-2014?

Comment: I have changed your *4-6 years ago* to *the past 4-6 year*, assuming that you want data for the last 4-6 years (and not 4-6 year old data only).

Answer (score 1):

Looking around on the [USGS EarthExplorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/), there are a few options available but none of them are available at the spatial scale you need (the finest, eMODIS, is at 250m). Your other option is to perform the calculation yourself, using slightly processed images, though the best resolutions you'll find won't be below 90 metres, at best.

You might have to wait a few more years for the data to become more easily accessible, but NDVI at the sub 250m-scale will always be quite valuable.

(If you're willing to pay for the images, the IKONOS-2 satellite has pancromatic imagery below the metre-scale, but that's not really what OpenData.se is about).